# Bresenham's line plot does not work as intended

Tags: python, arrays, graphics

Currently it plots the lines correctly, but draws an additional line between the points (not wanted).
Intent: plot two lines, not three. Have the two lines disconnected. The two lines are connected in this code.

```
pnts = [[100, 150],
[200, 300],   # these two points
[500, 620],   # should not make a line
[700, 500]]

canvas = np.ones((800,800), np.uint8)
def setPixel(x, y):
    canvas[y, x] = 255

for i in range(0, len(pnts) - 1):
    x0 = pnts[i][0]
    y0 = pnts[i][1]
    x1 = pnts[i+1][0]
    y1 = pnts[i+1][1]
    dx = abs(x1 - x0)
    dy = abs(y1 - y0)
    sx = 1 if x0 < x1 else -1
    sy = 1 if y0 < y1 else -1
    err = dx - dy
    while True:
        setPixel(x0, y0)
        if x0 == x1 and y0 == y1:
            break
        e2 = 2 * err
        if e2 > -dy:
            err = err - dy
            x0 = x0 + sx
        if e2 < dx:
            err = err + dx
            y0 = y0 + sy

cv2.imwrite('plot lines1.jpg', canvas)
cv2.imshow('image', canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Unsure what to change in the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide a [mre]. Anyway, see [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You should change the ```range()``` call to ```range(0, len(pnts), 2)```.

Comment: Very impressive. My regards for the solution & wise quip.